# Objective-c and garbage collection

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection

If I code an objective-c program can I rely on the system to garbage collect efficiently?

Comment: What are your expected efficiency indicators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Bavarious's point, it depends on what your expectation of efficiency is. Putting that aside, note that garbage collection is only available on OS X, not iOS.

Comment: Does this mean I need to release any memory allocated by objects I created on the iPhone?

Comment: In a word: Yes. But memory management isn't the horrible soul-sucking nightmare that GC proponents would have you believe - just pay attention to the ownership rules, and let the accessor methods created by using `@property` handle the details. In practice, retain/release is pretty much just as painless as fully-automatic GC. To learn about MM, see Apple's guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: Memory Management with Objective-C is actually quite easy and intuitive, for the most part. Don't be scared of it!